# Playing sound on button click while moving to other page C#

Tags: c#, button, audio, navigation

I'm using C# and I'm trying to make my button click which navigates me to a new page, to play a sound. The problem is that I can't hear the sound playing because the media element is in the previous page. Is there a way to play a sound but to hear it in all pages? 
Here is my code:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Game));
        select.Play();
    }
```

select is my sound .wav and it plays if I don't have the navigation code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing a soundfile going from one form to the other like this should work fine.
I placed my file in a Sounds folder inside the project

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.Storage;

private async void ButtonPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MediaElement snd = new MediaElement();
    StorageFolder folder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Sounds");
    StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("Alarm01.wav");
    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    snd.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
    snd.Play();
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Game));

 }
```

Comment: u need to import using Windows.ApplicationModel; and using Windows.Storage; i made an edit

Comment: lol it was my bad sorry... I just forgot the void...
I already imported those ;)
Thank you very much  it WORKED! :D

Comment: Actually it didn't work perfectly... I still have a problem. The sound only plays the second time I press the button... When I first press the button and navigate to game there is no sound, but if i go back to main menu again and then press it again only then i hear the sound

Comment: It plays perfect from the first time on my clean test project. Maybe rebuild your project and make sure the file is embedded.

Comment: Just tried and it's the same thing :/
I don't know what's wrong... I build it , rebuild it and all but nothing changed

Comment: I tried this on another button and it actually worked from the first time... so I guess I'll just remake the other button and it should be fine... :)
thanks again :D

Comment: Unfortunatly it didn't work again... :/
it wasn't the button's fault but the navigated page's.
The other button that I told you it work from the first time it was because it was navigating to another page... but when I changed it to navigate to the smae page as the one that the button failed to play sound from the first time, it didn't play sound either

Comment: code is like 300+ lines on that page... so it's kinda hard to do that :/
If you don't have any good guess, it's ok I'll try to find a solution... ;)

Answer (score 1):

This way the problem that I had that the sound couldn't play the first time the app opens is fixed. :)

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.Storage;



MediaElement snd = new MediaElement();

    private async void ButtonPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFolder folder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Sounds");
    StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("Alarm01.wav");
    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    snd.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Game));
 }
```