# Load all pages on initialization

Tags: c#

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and I made a C# windows store app. Is there a way to load a page from another page without navigating to it? Basically I want to load all pages when the app starts to solve some problems that I'm facing.

So let's say I have MainPage and I want to load Page1, but without actual navigation to the page. How can I do that?

I suppose I could just make the program do navigate to all pages when the app starts and just add a loading screen ot the top layer until everything loads up.But I'm guessing there will be a better way to do this.

Thanks! :)

Comment: You may want to look into BDD, for example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32512/Behavior-Driven-Development-with-NBehave

Comment: Thanks for this article. It's very interesting, but I don't see how it could help me with my problem. :/
Did I miss something?

Comment: Possibly! The idea behind BDD for web development is that you create series of behaviors (tests) for each page and then run the tests after each build. So after you are done writing the tests then all your pages will be automatically tested after build, which seems to be what you are after.
For your exact case you could just write empty tests case for each page that loads it, and in the future fill it as you see fit (BDD is a really good practice).

Comment: Well I still can't see it. Also I don't see any code indicating that it's working with different pages for an app ,and I'm not doing web development. This is an app that I'm making for the microsoft app store.

Comment: Maybe provide some detail on the issues that you are facing?  It might be that those issues are easier to solve?

Comment: Ok. The problem is that when I press a button to navigate from a page to another the sound I want to play when the button is pressed doesn't work at the first time the app runs, but if I go to that other page, then return to main page and then again navigate to the other page again, only then I can hear the sound. At first I had this issue with only one page, but now I have this problem with every page. What I noticed is that this problem started happening when those pages had too much code and UI objects. So I thought that I just had to load all pages to fix it.

Comment: All the code that I used is from a previous question that I had, where you will find all the code that I used for the sound play: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032225/playing-sound-on-button-click-while-moving-to-other-page-c-sharp

Comment: Without looking too deeply into the issue, is this something that could be solved by loading all the sounds at application startup and caching them?

Comment: I'm not sure but it could be a solution... How do I do that?